# Shared object "libarchive.so.7" not found, required by "pkg"

Tags: freebsd, dynamic-linking, pkg

I'm using FreeBSD 12-CURRENT and recently I tried to update my packages with `pkg`.

`pkg update` finished successfully, but `pkg upgrade` returned the following error:

> ```
> Shared object "libarchive.so.5" not found, required by "pkg"
> ```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First of all, try `pkg bootstrap -f` (or `pkg install -f pkg`).
2. If it fails then try `pkg-static bootstrap -f` (or `pkg-static install -f pkg`) as it doesn't require any shared objects.
3. If everything else doesn't work then you can install `pkg` from ports:

   ```
    cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg
    make
    make reinstall clean
   ```

You should be able to use `pkg` now.

---

Also, remember that there are two programs called `pkg` in FreeBSD. See [`man 7 pkg`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7&n=1) and [`man 8 pkg`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8&n=1) for more details.

Related:

- [pkg broken after upgrading from 9.3 to 10.1](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/51659/)